# Mysql replace query on multiple input check-box group

Tags: mysql

My database contains the following table:

```
answers(answer_id,question_id,answer_text)
```

And in the html, I have a group of 9 check-boxes. They all look like this-

```
<input id='1' type='checkbox' name="ques[]" value="1st input." />
.
.
.
<input id='9' type='checkbox' name="ques[]" value="9th input."/>
```

I am using the following mysql query currently-

```
replace INTO answers (q_id,answer_text) VALUES()//answer_id is auto increment.
```

The idea is that the user checks exactly three check-boxes and advances to the next question. He can also re-answer this question. Hence I need to replace records whenever the same question is re-answered.
I have put in a unique key index on `question_id`. But I also want to be able to save 3 check box inputs to the same question, and then replace all the three upon re-answering.
What changes do I do to my database to do this? Is my dB not normalized?

Comment: mysql is a database and has no checkboxes. Have you used a programming language? which? please edit your question and the tag.

Comment: I used a language of course! PHP. I want to know how I should structure my tables to solve my problem. That's all.

Comment: The checkboxes represent EITHER combinations OR permutations? Which?

Comment: the input is going to be a combination of 3 checkboxes.like- 1,3,4

Comment: So 4,1,3 is identical to 1,3,4?

Comment: yeah that makes no difference. I just want to be able to store all the tthree responses

Comment: I think I would have a table of checkbox texts, and then store the corresponding checkbox value in the answers table (rather than the text itself). But other than that, your answer table seems fit for purpose.

Comment: Thinking about it, all you need is question_id and a checkbox_id. The combination of these values forms a natural primary key.

Comment: I need a unique index so when the question is re-answered, no duplicate values are created. But that doesnt allow the multiple checkbox inputs. I need the table to accept exactly three answers(checkbox value or text). Then overwrite all the three upon a re-answer.

Comment: You don't need a 'unique index' for this.

Comment: How then do I overwrite the record on a re-answer?